# Calling API using Feign Client in a scheduler or staring request from kafka Listener got No thread-bound request found

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler, spring-cloud-feign, webcontext

I'm trying to use feign client in an spring boot project, everything works when starting the request from a controller class, but if start the request from an scheduler method or kafka listener, I get the following error:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request
> attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request
> outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually
> operating within a web request and still receive this message, your
> code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case,
> use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
> current request.

I tried many available solutions such as using *RequestContextFilter* and *RequestContextListener* but nothing happens.

Spring boot version is: 2.3.3.RELEASE

feign-httpclient: 13.0

spring-cloud-starter-openfeign: 2.2.10.RELEASE

I'll be so thankful if somebody can provide an idea for resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you share your attempts?